# Google Sheets - Parse unsorted comma separated values from one column, into separate columns. The values are not always in the same order

Tags: sql, json, google-sheets

Three example rows from that column are shown below.

```
{'gender': 'Female', 'document_type': 'driving_licence', 'date_of_expiry': '2024-03-03', 'issuing_country': 'GBR'}

{'nationality': 'DEU', 'document_type': 'national_identity_card', 'date_of_expiry': '2020-11-19', 'issuing_country': 'DEU'}

{'gender': 'Female', 'nationality': 'FRA', 'document_type': 'passport', 'date_of_expiry': '2024-01-22', 'issuing_country': 'FRA'}
```

My desired outcome would be:

```
gender | document_type | document_type | date_of_expiry | issuing country | nationality | national_identity_card |
```

e.g.

```
Female | driving_licence | 2024-03-03 | GBR | NULL | NULL 
NULL   | national_identity_card | 2020-11-19 | DEU | DEU
.
.
.
```

Any help would be great :)

Comment: your input it's similar to a JSON, it's not a CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it looks like JSON. You could replace all the `'` with `"` and paste the records here: https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer

The complete string for the examples you provided would be:

```json
{
  "example": [
    {
      "gender": "Female",
      "document_type": "driving_licence",
      "date_of_expiry": "2024-03-03",
      "issuing_country": "GBR"
    },
    {
      "nationality": "DEU",
      "document_type": "national_identity_card",
      "date_of_expiry": "2020-11-19",
      "issuing_country": "DEU"
    },
    {
      "gender": "Female",
      "nationality": "FRA",
      "document_type": "passport",
      "date_of_expiry": "2024-01-22",
      "issuing_country": "FRA"
    }
  ]
}
```

After that, clicking the button `JSON to CSV` generates the values sorted by columns like this:

```
gender,document_type,date_of_expiry,issuing_country
Female,driving_licence,2024-03-03,GBR
,national_identity_card,2020-11-19,DEU
Female,passport,2024-01-22,FRA
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I am going to try this out and see how it works out. I will share an update soon :)

Comment: @jota - I was able to get what I wanted with some adjustments. Thank you very much, once again :)

Answer (score 0):

While the answer from @jota seems to have solved your problem, I have an alternative solution for that works mostly automatically, though it depends if you always receive the data as objects, ideally in an array.

#### A potential Apps Script solution

First you need to create a Google Sheet and fill in the headers. The text must match **exactly** the title of the property titles you are receiving. For example, `document_type` not `Document Type`.

[image: headers in sheet]

Then open the Script Editor by clicking on the 'Tools' menu, then select 'Script editor...'.

Replace the code with the following:

```js
function addToSheet() {

  // Ideally this data gets created automatically but here is the example you gave.
  let example = [
    {
      gender: "Female",
      document_type: "driving_licence",
      date_of_expiry: "2024-03-03",
      issuing_country: "GBR",
    },
    {
      nationality: "DEU",
      document_type: "national_identity_card",
      date_of_expiry: "2020-11-19",
      issuing_country: "DEU",
    },
    {
      gender: "Female",
      nationality: "FRA",
      document_type: "passport",
      date_of_expiry: "2024-01-22",
      issuing_country: "FRA",
    },
  ];

  // Defining where to put the data
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Spreadsheet the script is attached to
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Put the name of your sheet here
  let sheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // Gets all data from sheet.

  // Take headers from data
  let headers = sheetData.shift(); // removes first row, which is the headers, of data and assigns to variable

  // For each entry, create an array, and fill it according to the header structure.
  example.forEach((entry) => {
    
    let newRow = []; // initializing new array
  
    // build the new row according to the header structure.
    headers.forEach(header => {
      newRow.push(entry[header]); // add cell value to row, if not present in entry, will fill with undefined
    })
    
    sheet.appendRow(newRow); // add built row to sheet
  });
}
```

I adapted the structure provided by @jota. What would be up to you is to adapt the data you are getting to be an array of objects. What I have defined as `example`, would be the necessary format.

Then if you run the code, it will append the rows in the right place.

[image: autofill]

#### References and explanation

- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) - the service within Apps Script that allows you to manipulate spreadsheets.
- [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) - the spreadsheet object.
- [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) - the sheet object, in the example above, the sheet must be named "Sheet1" - though you can change that in your code to adapt to your needs, of course.
- [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) - The methods associated with ranges (selections etc).
- [Append Row](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents) - The method used to add the row at the end.
- [getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) - The method used to select the range containing all the data in the particular sheet. In this case, it is used to dynamically get the headers.
- [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) - Used in conjunction with `getDataRange` to actually return the values. `getDataRange` only returns the `range` object which *contains* the values, but has a lot more to it too. With `getValues` you get a simple two dimensional array.

The script gets the headers in an array, it uses the `headers` array to build a row for the sheet for each object defined in `example`, and appends each row to the sheet after its built.

This can be adapted to many situations, but the advantage it has, is that the object can have all or none of the fields, in any order, and it will update the spreadsheet correctly regardless. As mentioned previously, the only issue you may encounter, is getting the initial data into the right format.

Comment: Thank you very much, @iansedano, for looking into this. Appreciate your help :)